# Traefik query alive/dead backends

Tags: docker-swarm, traefik

We have a treafik installation on docker swarm with several services balanced through traefik. Each service has at least two backends balanced with wrr and a healthcheck.

Is there a way (api, rest endpoint, logfile whatever) to find out which frontends have dead backends? By dead I mean on which backends treafik has detected via healthcheck that they are not eligible for balancing?

What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways of getting that info:

#### Traefik log

Look at [Traefik log](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/logs/#traefik-logs) which provides traces for healthchecks:

> ```
> time="2019-03-05T22:19:35Z" level=debug msg="Refreshing health check for backend: backend-web-so-55004614",
> time="2019-03-05T22:19:35Z" level=warning msg="Health check still failing. Backend: \"backend-web-so-55004614\" URL: \"http://192.168.80.2:80\" Reason: received error status code: 404",
> time="2019-03-05T22:19:36Z" level=debug msg="Refreshing health check for backend: backend-web-so-55004614",
> time="2019-03-05T22:19:36Z" level=warning msg="Health check still failing. Backend: \"backend-web-so-55004614\" URL: \"http://192.168.80.2:80\" Reason: received error status code: 404",
> ```

### Traefik `/metrics`

If it is not convenient to parse Traefik logs, you could active Traefik Prometheus metrics (which is enabled by default):

`docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -p "80:80" -p "8080:8080" traefik --api --docker`

Then you can make an HTTP query on `http://localhost:8080/metrics` and look for lines containing `_backend_server_up`. Each of these lines tells you that your backend is up and healthy. If a backend is missing, that means it is unhealthy or stopped:

```
traefik_backend_server_up{backend="backend-robots",url="http://172.23.0.3:80"} 1
traefik_backend_server_up{backend="backend-smtp-ui",url="http://172.25.0.3:8025"} 1
traefik_backend_server_up{backend="backend-varnish-admin",url="http://172.23.0.8:6085"} 1
traefik_backend_server_up{backend="backend-varnish-http",url="http://172.23.0.8:6081"} 1
traefik_backend_server_up{backend="backend-web-apps",url="http://172.21.0.2:80"} 1
traefik_backend_server_up{backend="backend-web-report",url="http://172.19.0.6:80"} 1
```

You could have a script querying this URL or you could install Prometheus which has [alerting rules](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/)

Comment: Ok thanks for the hint, at least that's a hint when something goes wrong. But it's not suitable for an automatic failure detection or monitoring (aka nagios etc.) :(

Comment: @Lasrik I found another way which uses Traefik metrics endpoint. I've edited my answer